# RemoteAuthenticationManager: how to configure?

Tags: spring-security

In reference to this question (["Server returned HTTP response code: 400 using Spring-Security AuthenticationProvider"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10657720/server-returned-http-response-code-400-using-spring-security-authenticationprov)), I've decided that I'm doing this all wrong. I'm trying to use a RESTful service to provide authentication that sends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationTokens back and forth, when I should be using a RemoteAuthenticationManager. (P.S. I'm ready to switch to basic auth, because this has been such a hassle. Unfortunately, that's not an option.)

So, I restructured.

Unfortunately, there is a dearth of examples of RemoteAuthenticationManagers.

I now have these beans in the server:

```
<bean id="remoteAuthenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.rcp.RemoteAuthenticationManagerImpl">
    <property name="authenticationManager">
        <ref bean="phsAuthenticationManager"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="phsAuthenticationManager" class="com.mystuff.phs.agent.service.AuthenticationManager">
    <property name="endpoint" value="${phs.authenticate.endpoint}" />
</bean>
```

The AuthenticationManager code is here:

```
@Service("phsAuthenticationManager")
@Transactional
public class AuthenticationManager implements RemoteAuthenticationManager {
    private String endpoint;

    /** authenticate call to PHS authenticate service. */
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> attemptAuthentication(String userName, String password) {
        ... // implementation details not important.
    }

    public String getEndpoint() {
        return this.endpoint;
    }

    public void setEndpoint(String endp) {
        this.endpoint = endp;
    }
}
```

So, I'm getting the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'remoteAuthenticationManager' defined in class path resource [phs-datasource.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type '$Proxy48 implementing org.springframework.security.authentication.rcp.RemoteAuthenticationManager,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised' to required type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' for property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [$Proxy48 implementing org.springframework.security.authentication.rcp.RemoteAuthenticationManager,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised] to required type [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager] for property 'authenticationManager': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

Maybe my brain is fried from a week of trying to configure what seems to be a pretty straightforward interface. Please help?

Editing for slight change to project files:

A coworker made some changes to the app-security.xml file and I've integrated the changes suggested here. Here is the app-security.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" 
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <http use-expressions="true" pattern="/rest/**" entry-point-ref="http403EntryPoint"
        authentication-manager-ref="remoteAuthenticationManager">
        <intercept-url pattern="/rest/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <custom-filter ref="tenantHmacFilter" position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    </http>

    <beans:bean id="http403EntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint">
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="tenantHmacFilter" class="com.mckesson.phs.agent.filter.TenantHmacFilter">
        <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="tenantHmacAuthenticationManager" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="tenantHmacAuthenticationManager" class="com.mckesson.phs.agent.filter.TenantHmacAuthenticationManager">
        <beans:property name="tenantId" value="${tenant.id}" />
        <beans:property name="tenantKey" value="${tenant.key}" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="remoteAuthenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.rcp.RemoteAuthenticationManagerImpl">
        <beans:property name="authenticationManager">
            <beans:ref local="authenticationManager" />
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="authenticationManager" class="com.mckesson.phs.agent.service.AuthenticationManagerImpl">
        <beans:property name="endpoint" value="${phs.authenticate.endpoint}" />
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

Here is the complete trace stack:

```
Wed 12:43:04.171 ERROR org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager: Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@15c44d6] to prepare test instance [com.mckesson.phs.agent.dao.AppointmentDaoImplTest@ab436d]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:157)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0' while setting constructor argument with key [7]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0' while setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'remoteAuthenticationManager' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'remoteAuthenticationManager' defined in class path resource [app-security.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type '$Proxy47 implementing com.mckesson.phs.agent.service.AuthenticationManager,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised' to required type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' for property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [$Proxy47 implementing com.mckesson.phs.agent.service.AuthenticationManager,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised] to required type [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager] for property 'authenticationManager': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:153)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:567)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:103)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(DelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:148)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0' while setting constructor argument with key [7]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0' while setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'remoteAuthenticationManager' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'remoteAuthenticationManager' defined in class path resource [app-security.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type '$Proxy47 implementing com.mckesson.phs.agent.service.AuthenticationManager,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised' to required type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' for property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [$Proxy47 implementing com.mckesson.phs.agent.service.AuthenticationManager,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised] to required type [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager] for property 'authenticationManager': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:153)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:616)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:148)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:939)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0' while setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'remoteAuthenticationManager' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'remoteAuthenticationManager' defined in class path resource [app-security.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type '$Proxy47 implementing com.mckesson.phs.agent.service.AuthenticationManager,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised' to required type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' for property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [$Proxy47 implementing com.mckesson.phs.agent.service.AuthenticationManager,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised] to required type [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager] for property 'authenticationManager': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'remoteAuthenticationManager' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'remoteAuthenticationManager' defined in class path resource [app-security.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type '$Proxy47 implementing com.mckesson.phs.agent.service.AuthenticationManager,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised' to required type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' for property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [$Proxy47 implementing com.mckesson.phs.agent.service.AuthenticationManager,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised] to required type [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager] for property 'authenticationManager': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:616)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:148)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:939)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 73 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'remoteAuthenticationManager' defined in class path resource [app-security.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type '$Proxy47 implementing com.mckesson.phs.agent.service.AuthenticationManager,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised' to required type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' for property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [$Proxy47 implementing com.mckesson.phs.agent.service.AuthenticationManager,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised] to required type [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager] for property 'authenticationManager': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 85 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type '$Proxy47 implementing com.mckesson.phs.agent.service.AuthenticationManager,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised' to required type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' for property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [$Proxy47 implementing com.mckesson.phs.agent.service.AuthenticationManager,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised] to required type [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager] for property 'authenticationManager': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1406)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1365)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    ... 91 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [$Proxy47 implementing com.mckesson.phs.agent.service.AuthenticationManager,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised] to required type [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager] for property 'authenticationManager': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:241)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:470)
    ... 97 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error that you are getting is because of type mismatch. The Spring Security authenticationManager is configured like this:

```
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" erase-credentials="true">
    ...
</security:authentication-manager>
```

This is then wired to `RemoteAuthenticationManagerImpl`:

```
<bean id="remoteAuthenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.rcp.RemoteAuthenticationManagerImpl">
    <property name="authenticationManager"><ref local="authenticationManager" /></property>
</bean>
```

If you are looking for HttpInvoker solution (both ends Spring) then above is configured like this:

```
<bean name="/RemoteAuthenticationManager" class="org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerServiceExporter">
    <property name="service"><ref local="remoteAuthenticationManager"/></property>
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="org.springframework.security.authentication.rcp.RemoteAuthenticationManager" />
</bean>
```

Please add more details on what you are trying to do. Are you implementing Spring Security in a distributed application something like [Spring Security in a distributed application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342096/spring-security-in-a-distributed-application) or [Spring HTTP Invoker Authentication Questions](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?123778-Spring-HTTP-Invoker-Authentication-Questions)?

Comment: I have a server (Spring/Hibernate) that is responsible for calling a web service or LDAP server for authentication, as well as other services, such as data access. I have a client-server application (GWT/Spring/Hibernate) that will use these services. Thus the remote authentication manager.

Comment: The app-security.xml has changed and I've included it above.

Comment: Also the complete trace stack.

Comment: authenticationManager property of RemoteAuthenticationManagerImpl is of type org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager and so you cannot wire it to com.mckesson.phs.agent.service.AuthenticationManagerImpl, which is implementing RemoteAuthenticationManager. I sugegst first configure  spring security in your application and test it with a normal login form and then implement RemoteAuthentication. You can remove (or block) form login later if you don't need it. First step is to configure security:authentication-manager with authentication providers that you need.